# Работа с большим количеством ресурсов Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

Я подгружаю список телеканалов и их адреса с сервера, у каждого телеканала есть иконка. Список телеканалов может изменяться, в drawables я храню все иконки, около 40.

Как лучше организовать присваивание иконок телеканалам, что бы потом выводить их список?

В мыслях: создание карты <название телеканала,ссылка на ресурс>, потом поиск по карте и присваивание ссылки объекту телеканала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить id ресурса по имени, вот так

```
getResources().getIdentifier("my_drawable_name", "drawable", getPackageName())
```

Тут можно сделать более гибкий подход. И мапить ничего не надо.

Comment: У меня имена каналов на русском.

Comment: @АнатолийСивенко вы с сырвера только имен каналов получаете? у вас явно там какая-то моделька. а значит можно сделать не по имени канала, а по id, или какому-то другому параметру.

Comment: Так же получаю адрес. Спасибо большое.